# Google Cloud Labels : Inherit labels to resource from project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-resource-manager

Any Suggestions how we can apply and govern Labels automatically on google resources. As Google Cloud Labels are not inheriting from project. What all we can do update the system and user label with automation.

Its will help on CMDB and Billing prospective.

Comment: i saw the post this is not related to My question :)

Comment: There is a [post from a community blog](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-asset-inventory-auto-label-resources) which explains how to label resources automatically based on Cloud Asset Inventory real-time notifications. Unsure if this could be useful to you, or you may create a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) for that purpose.